# Cannot get Mosquitto <-> AWS IoT -bridge to stay connected

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, mosquitto, aws-iot

I am running Mosquitto Broker on AWS Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS server. I have 2 MQTT bridges, from my laptop to the broker on the server and from the server to AWS IoT.

My broker configuration on the server is as follows:

```
listener 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 9001
protocol websockets

allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/passwd.txt

connection awsiot
address xxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com:8883

topic iotethernet/switch/count out 1
topic iotethernet/ledblock/states in 1

bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_insecure false
bridge_outgoing_retain false

cleansession true
clientid bridgeawsiot
start_type automatic
notifications true
log_type all

bridge_cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/rootCA.pem
bridge_certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/cert.crt
bridge_keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/private.key
```

The problem is that when I am running the server, the bridge client constantly connects and immediately disconnects without an error message.

[image: Picture of mosquitto broker after bridge client disconnects]

I have made sure that the bridge doesn't work by testing with the AWS IoT -test feature.

The bridge from laptop to server works fine.

Answer (score 2):

i got it working by setting notifications to false